# Choosing Correct Source filter For mov Files

Tags: c++, windows, directx, media-player, directshow

I have Medialooks QT Source installed in my Desktop and when I choose **Render File** option from graphedt or graphedtnext tool it chooses Medialooks Qt source as source filter and constructs a graph. But if i call **m_grahBuilder->RenderFile()** in my Application it is selecting Asyncreader as Source Filter and eventally my graph creation is failed. I have gone through graphedtnext's source code .They are also using **RenderFile()**  Function for creating graph automatically.How to make Directshow select correct filter automatically (I dont want to add using CLS_ID ) .I am just wondering how graphedt and graphedtnxt work in these scenarios .

Comment: Have you checked if you application is running in 32 bit mode? If the Medialooks QT Source is a 32 bit filter it can't be loaded in a 64 bit application. You can check that also with the 64 bit version of graphstudionext.

Comment: Its 32 bit application and .If I Load manually (Using CLS_ID and AddFilter())its loading properly